# What is the best way to reference another Stack Overflow question or answer?

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks

What is the best way to refer to another question or answer?  Do I just link it as a standard url, is there a better way?

`[short description of question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123456)`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In posts, just paste the link, and the title will be supplied automatically. The link to this question is:

```
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266057/what-is-the-best-way-to-reference-another-stackoverflow-question-answer
```

and renders as

[What is the best way to reference another Stack Overflow question or answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266057/what-is-the-best-way-to-reference-another-stackoverflow-question-answer)

In comments, you'll have to do your own title formatting. I use a [user script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2378/se-comment-link-helper) that automatically replaces Stack Exchange links with the title and the shortest form; your link would be replaced by:

```
[What is the best way to reference another stackoverflow question/answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266057)
```

using the shorter `http://sitehostname/q/<postid>` form. For answers you can use `http://sitehostname/a/<postid>`; e.g. this answer can be linked to with `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266058`.

Comment: Any explanation behind the fact that comment links are not directly changed into title links ? Wouldn't it be better in any case ?

Comment: @ClémentMalet: see [Replace links with the current question title in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77394); Jeff Atwood states that because comments are processed on the fly that would incur too many database queries.